# column names in row with their value sql

Tags: sql

I have two tables and Table1 has all the values which I need to fill in Table2. How can I get column name in row with their values?

Table1:

| s.no | ID | Function | Head | Subhead | Via | transferID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A529 | Service | Cost | Cost | online | 456789 |
| 2 | A432 | Part change | cost | Cost | Cash | 1000 |

Table2:

| Serial no. | Feild_name | Feild_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Function | service |
| 1 | Head | Cost |
| 1 | Subhead | Cost |
| 1 | Via | Online |
| 2 | Function | Part change |
| 2 | Head | cost |
| 2 | Subhead | cost |
| 2 | Via | online |

Comment: sql server or Oracle? Please don't tag products not involved

Comment: I've removed the conflicting tags; please [edit] your question to retag the *actual* RDBMS you are using. *(Also, it's spelt f**ie**ld not f*ei*ld, but columns are* not *"fields", they are columns.)*

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can run 4 queries for the 4 categories and then join them with UNION ALL.
NB this method will not work if we add new categories.
This is coded in SQL server but should work for most RDBMS.

> ```
> create table t(
> s_no  int,
> ID    char(4),
> Functionn varchar(25),
> Head      varchar(25),
> Subhead       varchar(25),
> Via       varchar(25),
> transferID int);
> insert into t values
> (1,'A529','Service','Cost','Cost','online',456789),
> (2,'A432','Part change','cost','Cost','Cash',1000);
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 2 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select s_no serial_number, 'Function' "Field Name", Functionn "Field Value" from t
> union all
> select s_no serial_number, 'Head' ,Head from t
> union all
> select s_no serial_number, 'Sub-Head' ,Subhead from t
> union all
> select s_no serial_number, 'Via' ,Via from t
> order by s_no,"Field Name"
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> serial_number | Field Name | Field Value
> ------------: | :--------- | :----------
>             1 | Function   | Service    
>             1 | Head       | Cost       
>             1 | Sub-Head   | Cost       
>             1 | Via        | online     
>             2 | Function   | Part change
>             2 | Head       | cost       
>             2 | Sub-Head   | Cost       
>             2 | Via        | Cash
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=80542f6aa0c39f567788b798cc1fabf8)*

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server this can easily be done by [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-ver18) function, and using `INSERT INTO SELECT`.

Try:

```
insert into table2 (serial_no,
                    Feild_name,
                    Feild_value
                    )
select s_no as serial_no,
       Feild_name,
       Feild_value
FROM table1
unpivot
(
  Feild_value
  for Feild_name in (function_col,Head,Subhead,Via)
) unpiv;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=57f93af6e6d27b3331df90236d294dfc)